# login on update user role but not going on redirected or set pages if query matched

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysqli

## I have two table

1] Signup_users [first name , email_id , password , user_role]

2] add_business [name, email,address,phone,location]

what i need is when user login ,if **Email id** is matched with **two tables** , update **user_role** is **'customer'** else if not matched with both a table update as a **'user'** ,

but what happening in my case , **

> it's all working i can login and user_role is updated, but not working redirecting pages as per login , for that i need to logout then again login then it's work well .

so what i want if i login same time update the user_role and same time if query matched go to defined page as per user_role ,but redirecting pages working when i logout and login again then it's work.please look for last **update** query
**Please Help**

sorry for english if not get it to you.

```
<?php  include ('../database_connection/db_connection.php'); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

//Log in SCRIPT for User Sign in

if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){

$email_username =  $_POST['sign_in_email'];
$password = $_POST['sign_in_password'];

$email_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$email_username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connection,$password);

$username_get = "SELECT * FROM signup_users WHERE email_id = '{$email_username}'";
$username_connection = mysqli_query($connection,$username_get);

if(!$username_connection){
die("MYSQLI_ERROR". mysqli_error($connection));
 }




while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($username_connection)){

$db_user_id = $row['user_id'];
$db_full_name = $row['full_name'];
$db_email_id = $row['email_id'];
$db_password = $row['password'];
$db_user_role = $row['user_role'];

}
if($email_username !== $db_email_id && $password !== $db_password)
{
   header("LOCATION: index.php");
}
  else if($email_username == $db_email_id && $password == $db_password  &&  $db_user_role == 'customer'){

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $db_user_id; 
$_SESSION['full_name'] = $db_full_name; 
$_SESSION['email_id'] = $db_email_id; 
$_SESSION['password'] = $db_password; 
    $_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;

 header("LOCATION: ../dashboard/dashboard_overview.php");

}
else {
header("LOCATION: index.php");
}

$select_two_tables_email = "SELECT signup_users.email_id  , addbusiness.email  FROM signup_users inner join addbusiness on  signup_users.email_id = addbusiness.email AND signup_users.email_id = '{$email_username}' AND addbusiness.email = '{$email_username}'  ";
$select_two_table_query = mysqli_query($connection,$select_two_tables_email);


if(mysqli_num_rows($select_two_table_query) == $select_two_table_query)
{

$update_query_email  = "UPDATE signup_users SET user_role = 'customer' WHERE  email_id = '{$email_username}' ";
$select_query_mysqli = mysqli_query($connection,$update_query_email);
         }
else if(mysqli_num_rows($select_two_table_query)!== $select_two_table_query){
$update_query_email_id  = "UPDATE signup_users SET user_role = 'user' WHERE  email_id = '{$email_username}' ";
$select_query_mysqli = mysqli_query($connection,$update_query_email_id);

}
else{
$update_query_email_blank  = "UPDATE signup_users SET user_role = 'blank' WHERE  email_id = '{$email_username}' ";
$select_query_blank = mysqli_query($connection,$update_query_email_blank);

}  


} 



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept the code to update user role in the else condition where you check whether the user role is already 'customer' or not. And if you are updating the role to 'customer' then you get redirected to dashboard otherwise to index page. Hope this helps..

```
    <?php  include ('../database_connection/db_connection.php'); ?>
    <?php session_start(); ?>

    <?php

    //Log in SCRIPT for User Sign in

    if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){

    $email_username =  $_POST['sign_in_email'];
    $password = $_POST['sign_in_password'];

    $email_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$email_username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connection,$password);

    $username_get = "SELECT * FROM signup_users WHERE email_id = '{$email_username}'";
    $username_connection = mysqli_query($connection,$username_get);

    if(!$username_connection){
    die("MYSQLI_ERROR". mysqli_error($connection));
     }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($username_connection)){
        $db_user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $db_full_name = $row['full_name'];
        $db_email_id = $row['email_id'];
        $db_password = $row['password'];
        $db_user_role = $row['user_role'];
    }
    if($email_username !== $db_email_id && $password !== $db_password)
    {
       header("LOCATION: index.php");
    }
    else if($email_username == $db_email_id && $password == $db_password  &&  $db_user_role == 'customer'){

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $db_user_id; 
        $_SESSION['full_name'] = $db_full_name; 
        $_SESSION['email_id'] = $db_email_id; 
        $_SESSION['password'] = $db_password; 
        $_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;

        header("LOCATION: ../dashboard/dashboard_overview.php");

    }
    else {
        $select_two_tables_email = "SELECT signup_users.email_id  , addbusiness.email  FROM signup_users inner join addbusiness on  signup_users.email_id = addbusiness.email AND signup_users.email_id = '{$email_username}' AND addbusiness.email = '{$email_username}'  ";
        $select_two_table_query = mysqli_query($connection,$select_two_tables_email);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($select_two_table_query) == $select_two_table_query)
        {
            $update_query_email  = "UPDATE signup_users SET user_role = 'customer' WHERE  email_id = '{$email_username}' ";
            $select_query_mysqli = mysqli_query($connection,$update_query_email);

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $db_user_id; 
            $_SESSION['full_name'] = $db_full_name; 
            $_SESSION['email_id'] = $db_email_id; 
            $_SESSION['password'] = $db_password; 
            $_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;

            header("LOCATION: ../dashboard/dashboard_overview.php");
        }
        else if(mysqli_num_rows($select_two_table_query)!== $select_two_table_query){
            $update_query_email_id  = "UPDATE signup_users SET user_role = 'user' WHERE  email_id = '{$email_username}' ";
            $select_query_mysqli = mysqli_query($connection,$update_query_email_id);
            header("LOCATION: index.php");
        }
        else{
            $update_query_email_blank  = "UPDATE signup_users SET user_role = 'blank' WHERE  email_id = '{$email_username}' ";
            $select_query_blank = mysqli_query($connection,$update_query_email_blank);
            header("LOCATION: index.php");
        }              

    }

    } 

    ?>
```

Comment: your given query has worked but now user also can access dashobard page after login ,it should not be login , what should be i have to write in session